# How do I improve this question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[The EU Refunds law and wether cost of download is refundable?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/58388/the-eu-refunds-law-and-wether-cost-of-download-is-refundable) How do I improve this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is full of typographical and grammatical errors, some of which defy comprehension.

1. Run it through a spell checker.
2. Run it through a grammar checker.
3. Format it for readability.
4. Use [markdown for hyperlinks](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links).
5. Fix the word alignment in the image.